# how to read repeated chunk of data from a text file in a different variables

Tags: c#

In my application,I am reading a text file and storing in a byte array using ReadAllBytes method.Text file contains chunks of data.Each chunk contains Header followed by 15 bytes. Now How to read each chunk based on Header and store in a variable

Example:

> SLR-RMS 23 54 65 32 09 0.8 87 0.04 74 56 34 98 12 34 47 SLR-RMS 32
>   54 74 20 09 0.8 87 0.04 24 12 8.8 98 127 34 0.4 SLR-RMS 23 54 65 32 09
>   0.8 87 0.04 74 56 34 98 12 34 47.

SLR-RMS is the header.

Comment: Is this a binary or text file? If it's a text file, you don't want to use `ReadAllBytes()`.

Comment: Header always is the same?

Comment: Yes, its a  text file. I am reading it in a Byte array.

Comment: Yep,Header remains same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the file is a text file, you can read the text, and convert to double:

```
public static List<double[]> parse(string path) {
    // Read all words in the file and split on space
    string [] words = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath).Split();

    List<double[]> data = new List<double[]>();

    // Convert each string to double
    for (var i = 0; i < words.Length; i += 16) {
        double [] temp = new double[15];
        for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            temp[j] = Double.Parse(words[i+j+1]);
        }
        data.Add(temp);
    }
    return data;
}
```

TODO: Add some error checking in case the format of the file is corrupt.